# Store list of elements matching CSS selector in Selenium IDE variable

Tags: css, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I need to run automated tests on whether a Search engine is working correctly on a website - if a keyword is typed, to show only the results containing the specific keyword in their names.

I have to use only Selenium IDE (no WebDriver, no code).

So far, I have managed to define the CSS selectors needed, but do not know how to store an array of elements having this selector.

`store text` saved the text of the first element of the list (I have checked that the selector is fine by `document.querySelectorAll(".ajax_block_product .product-container a.product-name")` that gave me 7 elements):

**Command:** `store text`

**Target:** `css=.ajax_block_product .product-container a.product-name`

**Value:** `array`

Maybe I should use the `execute script` **command**, but how should I pass the list of elements corresponding to the CSS selector in **target** then?

As I could not find what command to use to save the texts of these 7 elements in an array that I need to iterate after through, can you please assist here or give some kind of workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `execute script` command to store array like this

```
Command | Target | Value
execute script | return document.querySelectorAll(".ajax_block_product .product-container a.product-name"); | array
```

`array` variable will contain these 7 elements.